# Get string values from vector

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure

I have this vector of strings:

`["Color: Black"
 "Color: Blue"
 "Size: S"
 "Size: XS"]`

How do I get all the values of `color` and `Size`?

For example, the output should be 
`["color" ["Black" "Blue"]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would rather do it in one pass with `reduce` (as it is shorter and probably faster):

```
user> (require '[clojure.string :as cs])
nil

user> (def data ["Color: Black" "Color: Blue" "Size: S" "Size: XS"])
#'user/data

user> (reduce #(let [[k v] (cs/split %2 #": ")]
                 (update %1 k (fnil conj []) v))
              {} data)
{"Color" ["Black" "Blue"], "Size" ["S" "XS"]}
```

Comment: I like this answer, maybe more than mine.  As is the case with most Clojure sequence functions, you can usually boil them down to a `reduce` pass.  However, I think it is harder to initially arrive at this solution unless you're used to thinking in terms of reduce.

Comment: i guess it is, but anyway, getting used to `reduce`/`fold` is kind of "necessary evil" when you choose the FP path ) (i mean the process of understanding, which could really be painful, by my experience)

Answer (score 4):

This solution splits each of the strings, groups by the attribute name (color, size, etc.), and then cleans up the expected values:

```
    user=> (require '[clojure.string :as string])
    nil

    user=> (def attributes ["Color: Black" "Color: Blue" "Size: S" "Size: XS"])
    #'user/attributes

    user=> (as-> attributes x
      #_=>   (map #(string/split % #": ") x)
      #_=>   (group-by first x)
      #_=>   (reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (mapv second %3)) {} x))
    {"Color" ["Black" "Blue"], "Size" ["S" "XS"]}
```

Comment: Neat use of the ```as->``` macro.

Comment: `as->` could be easily replaced with `->>`, since `x` is the last argument in all the forms. Also, 3 full passes over the collection (`map`, `group-by`, `reduce-kv` + `mapv` for every group), not to mention a bunch of intermediate collections, looks really redundant. So it's a nice answer to show the power of clojure sequence functions, but really bad one if you  want to actually use it in production.

Comment: @leetwinski I agree with most of your points.  I've started using `as->` for its clarity and its flexibility (when I want to add a step that doesn't fit the argument order of the other steps, I can do so).  I think this solution shows each step well at the expense of multiple passes.

Comment: @CurtisSummers, agreed about `as->` for different aggument places (wel it is its main purpose after all) but in this exact case i would say it obfuscates a bit. IMO